Calculate all combinations of adding (1+1) up X number of columns where one column is always constant
Lets say i have a data table that looks like this:

for each combination of index level1 & 2 - a customer could be allocated a price that see's them get the value base column + the addition of any combination of the a,b,c,d,e columns... including 0 addition, a max. of 5 additions and no repeated column additions (see example of what i mean by this below)...
i.e. combinations / permutation examples:
    Permutation1 = value_base
    Permutation2 = value_base  + value_add_a + value_add_b
    Permutation3 = value_base  + value_add_c
    Permutation4 = value_base  + value_add_c + value_add_d + value_add_e
    Permutation5 = value_base  + value_add_b + value_add_c + value_add_d
    Permutation6 = value_base  + value_add_a + value_add_d + value_add_e
    Permutation7 = value_base  + value_add_b + value_add_d + value_add_e
    Permutation8 = value_base  + value_add_e
and so on...
This example CANT occur:
    Permutation5 = value_base  + value_add_c + value_add_c + value_add_e
as _c appears more than once!
What I also don't want is to have "repeated" combinations - where the addition occurs in the same order:
ie. This:
    Permutation4 = value_base  + value_add_c + value_add_d + value_add_e
gives me the same result as this:
    Permutation4 = value_base  + value_add_c + value_add_e + value_add_d
so I DONT want this :)
I'm looking to code this up in python
currently stuck and unable to think of a solution that can keep a base constant..
import itertools
a = list(itertools.permutations([2, 3, 4, 5, 6]))
b = [1]
c = [list(permutation) + b for permutation in a]
print(c)

have tried looking at something like this - where b can be held constant, BUT the problem with this solution is that combinations can be repeated and the length of the additions is always 6 - where in my solution the length (number of columns added together) can be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 or 6 (given all possible combinations - remembering that b must be constant, and b can only be the only column addition outcome that has length 1)

IDK Python well enough to write anything useful, but you could use a Set to only keep the unique column combinations and just let it calculate them all. Or if the calculation is excessive, compare each found combo to the existing ones using one of the < or > Set operators.

You're probably looking for itertools.combinations, not .permutations
from itertools import combinations

def calculate(columns, base, spread=(0,5)):
    results = set()
    if spread[0] == 0:  # special case zero columns
        results.add(base)
    a, b = spread  # unpack to increment end in range
    for column_count in range(a, b+1):
        values = set(base + sum(c) for c in combinations(columns, column_count))
        results.update(values)
    return results

>>> calculate([1,2,3], 0)
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
>>> calculate([1,2,3], 0, spread=(1,2))
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
>>> calculate([1,2,3,4,5], 0)
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}
>>> calculate([1,2,3,4,5], 2, spread=(1,2))
{3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11}

NOTE sets are not ordered, but the values may appear in order
